# div wont contain all content inside of it

Tags: html

I have a div with a height of 100% and a solid border. when i have too much content, it will display outside the div border.

how do i expand the div to the height of all the content inside the border instead of just 100% of the screen size?

the height:100% seems to be measuring the screen height but not the content inside of it.

```
<style>
#container{
    height:100%;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
<div id="container">
```

[link](http://www.widgiteer.com/polls/) to problem sample page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a problem can be easily solved using the elusive clearfix! First off, remove all those `height:100%;` declarations you have for your `#container`, they're not needed, and try this in your CSS:

```
#container:before, #container:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  zoom: 1;
}

#container:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: i am wondering tho, i cant seem to get the footer at the bottom using the clearfix method. i have height:50px; clear:both; but it wont give itself room at the bottom of the div.

Comment: @user1082764 took another look at your site, you're not properly declaring your footer, remove that `position:absolute` declaration you have for it and declare a width, the same as the containers, `width:960px` and it should containe itself to the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

absolutely positioned elements do not change the height of their container. Your farbartastic element has absolute positioning, so it will be laid out without informing its container of its height requirements.

Comment: well the problem i am having is that the 100% is measuring the screen size but not the content inside. my notebook shows a very small box border but on my desktop the border covers almost everything.

Comment: a postition: relative is not the solution, because the problem is with elements that are floating outside the container

Comment: the problem is that elements are floating outside the container. the problem of the div with the background is what im trying to fix. the div height changes when the screen resolution changes.

Comment: i tried removing all position:relative and position:absolute elements. unfortunately it did not work :(

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems with yours floating element (which are flying outside the container), so , for correct this use `overflow:hidden` in the container

```
#container{
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```